# InternetSetCookie returns ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION

Tags: c#, wininet

I'm trying to expire a cookie on my machine. When I call into wininet.dll `InternetSetCookie` it returns `FALSE` and the error code is `4317` which is the generic `ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION`.

```
[DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool InternetSetCookie(string lpszUrlName, string lpszCookieName, string lpszCookieData);

public void Main()
{
     InternetSetCookie("http://example.com","cookieName","somevalue;expires=Mon, 01 Jan 0001 00:00:00 GMT")
}
```

Is there anyway to get more info on what operation was invalid?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anyway to get more info on what operation was invalid?

No there is not.

However, I was getting `ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION` because I was trying to set a cookie that has already been set ( I couldn't edit a cookie using `InternetSetCookie()` ). I had to clear all cookies using this [function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385114%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). You need to declare it first:

```
[DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool InternetSetOption(IntPtr hInternet,int dwOption,IntPtr lpBuffer, int lpdwBufferLength);
```

Then you can use it in the following fashion to clear the cookies ( [Note that `42` is `INTERNET_OPTION_END_BROWSER_SESSION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385328(v=vs.85).aspx)) :

```
bool isCleared=InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, 42, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
```